# direct jsp page by button onclick event without form tag

Tags: html, jsp

can we use input tag button without form tag and how to direct to another jsp page through onclick event?

I am trying to do this task by below code Here am trying to direct one editsurvey,jsp page through button onclick event without form tag.Can anyone explain the way I am using correct or incorrect?

```html
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: rajee
  Date: 2/16/15
  Time: 10:17 AM
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to survey</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    ResultSet rset;
    String sur_id = request.getParameter("surveyid");
    session.setAttribute( "surveyid", sur_id );
    int new_survey_id = Integer.parseInt(sur_id);

    if (request.getParameter("surveyid") == null) {
        out.println("Please enter your name.");
    } else {
        out.println("Hello <b>"+request.getParameter("surveyid")+"</b>!");
    }
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/surveysample", "root", "root");
    String query = "select * from surveydetail where surveyid ="+ new_survey_id ;
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while(rset.next()){
//        out.println(rset.getString(1));
//        out.println(rset.getString(2));
//        out.println(rset.getString(3));
//        out.println(rset.getString(4));
        %>
        <table border="3">
            <tr><td>Survey_Id</td><td><%=rset.getString(1)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Family name</td><td><%=rset.getString(2)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>First name</td><td><%=rset.getString(3)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Middle name</td><td><%=rset.getString(4)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>gender</td><td><%=rset.getString(5)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>dat of birth</td><td><%=rset.getString(6)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>income</td><td><%=rset.getString(7)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>complete address</td><td><%=rset.getString(8)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>coordinates</td><td><%=rset.getString(9)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>mobile number</td><td><%=rset.getString(10)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>email address</td><td><%=rset.getString(11)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>present Internet provider</td><td><%=rset.getString(12)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>comments</td><td><%=rset.getString(13)%></td></tr>
            <tr><td>remarks</td><td><%=rset.getString(14)%></td></tr>
            <br>
            <table>
                <tr><td><input type="button" value="edit" onclick="javascript:document.forms[0].action = 'EditSurvey.jsp'; document.forms[0].submit();"></td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                    <td><input type="button" value="delete"></td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                    <td><input type="button" value="print"></td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                    <td><input type="button" value="send mail"></td>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                </tr>
            </table>

        </table>
        <%
    }

%>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

HI i think you can use the following code

```
<button type="submit" formaction="demo_admin.asp">Submit as admin</button>
```

In the formaction attribute you can use your form name where you want to redirect.